# Using cross-validation to select optimal threshold: binary classification in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I have a Keras model that takes a transformed vector x as input and outputs probabilities that each input value is 1.

I would like to take the predictions from this model and find an optimal threshold. That is, maybe the cutoff value for "this value is 1" should be 0.23, or maybe it should be 0.78, or something else. I know cross-validation is a good tool for this.

My question is how to work this in to training. For example, say I have the following model (taken from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/binary-classification-tutorial-with-the-keras-deep-learning-library/)):

```
def create_baseline():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(60, input_dim=60, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I train the model and get some output probabilities:

```
model.fit(train_x, train_y)
predictions = model.predict(train_y)
```

Now I want to learn the threshold for the value of each entry in `predictions` that would give the best accuracy, for example. How can I learn this parameter, instead of just choosing one after training is complete?

EDIT: For example, say I have this:

```
def fake_model(self):

    #Model that returns probability that each of 10 values is 1
    a_input = Input(shape=(2, 10), name='a_input')
    dense_1 = Dense(5)(a_input)
    outputs = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(dense_1)

    def hamming_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return tf.to_float(tf.reduce_sum(abs(y_true - y_pred))) /tf.to_float(tf.size(y_pred))

    fakemodel = Model(a_input, outputs)

    #Use the outputs of the model; find the threshold value that minimizes the Hamming loss
    #Record the final confusion matrix.
```

How can I train a model like this end-to-end?

Comment: Sure, it sounds like you're looking to implement some boosting. I mean, you could just look for an ideal cut-off value, like you said... or you could pass `actual - predicted` into another model trying to minimize it. Either way you achieve a similar result, and with this method you open the possibility of accuracy improvements. Just a thought!

Comment: Thanks @TheLoneDeranger. Is there a way to train that whole system end-to-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an ROC curve isn't what you are looking for, you could create a custom Keras Layer that takes in the outputs of your original model and tries to learn an optimal threshold given the true outputs and the predicted probabilities.

This layer subtracts the threshold from the predicted probability, multiplies by a relatively large constant (in this case 100) and then applies the sigmoid function. Here is a plot that shows the function at three different thresholds (.3, .5, .7).

[image]

Below is the code for the definition of this layer and the creation of a model that is composed solely of it, after fitting your original model, feed it's outputs probabilities to this model and start training for an optimal threshold.

```
class ThresholdLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ThresholdLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name="threshold", shape=(1,), initializer="uniform",
                                      trainable=True)
        super(ThresholdLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        return keras.backend.sigmoid(100*(x-self.kernel))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

out = ThresholdLayer()(input_layer)
threshold_model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=out)
threshold_model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mse")
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for your answer. Why is it necessary to subtract the threshold and multiply by a large number?

Comment: This is an approximation to the thresholding function, let's say we have a probability of .6 as input and a threshold of .5, by subtracting the threshold, you get a positive result (.1), multiplying it by a large constant then applying softmax, would simply result in a 1. If the input probability was less than the threshold, the result will be negative, and multiplying it by a large constant and then applying softmax, would result to 0. 
Check the plots I have attached to my answer for better visualization of the function.

Answer (score 0):

First, here's a direct answer to your question. You're thinking of an [ROC curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). For example, assuming some data `X_test` and `y_test`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import auc

y_pred = model.predict(X_test).ravel()

fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)

my_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='Model_name (area = {:.3f})'.format(my_auc))
plt.xlabel('False positive rate')
plt.ylabel('True positive rate')
plt.title('ROC curve')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()

plt.figure(2)
plt.xlim(0, 0.2)
plt.ylim(0.8, 1)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='Model_name (area = {:.3f})'.format(my_auc))
plt.xlabel('False positive rate')
plt.ylabel('True positive rate')
plt.title('ROC curve close-up')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Second, regarding my comment, [here's an example of one attempt.](https://alan.do/deep-gradient-boosted-learning-4e33adaf2969) It can be done in Keras, or TF, or anywhere, although he does it with XGBoost.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think I'm looking for something more along the lines of https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#more-examples (Shared vision model), where I can use one loss for training the first model and a different loss (accuracy-based) for training the next. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

First idea I have is kind of brute force.
You compute on a test set a metric separately for each of your input and its corresponding predicted output.
Then for each of them iterate over values for the threshold betzeen 0 and 1 until the metric is optimized for the given input/prediction pair.

Answer (score 0):

For many of the popular metrics of classification quality (accuracy, precision, recall, etc) you just **cannot** learn the optimal threshold while training your neural network.

This is because these metrics are not differentiable - therefore, gradient updates will fail to set the threshold (or any other parameter) correctly. Therefore, you are forced to optimize a nice smooth loss (like negative log likelihood) during training most of the parameters, and then tune the threshold by grid search.

Of course, you can come up with a smoothed version of your metric and optimize it (and sometimes people do this). But in most cases it is OK to optimize log-likelihood, get a nice probabilistic classifier, and tune the thresholds on top of it.  E.g. if you want to optimize accuracy, then you should first estimate class probabilities as accurately as possible (to get close to the perfect Bayes classifier), and then just choose their argmax.

Comment: Hmm. I agree in principle, but I wonder if you can do a nice little trick like is used with autoencoders - if you have a discrete hidden layer, you can use a continuous approximation (that is reasonably close to the original discrete distribution) and differentiate through that.